# Is there a tool for TFS which quickly view the author of one line code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm working with a team and have to read to understand their codes. I want to know the author of a certain line of code but at the moment, I'm not sure how to do it quickly except I have to browse the history for that - which is very time-consuming.

Do you have any addon/tips for me? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the solution explorer find the file then right click "Annotate".

See the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385979.aspx) on the command.

The command will go through the history of the file and will show who changed what line and when, on the sidebar.